# Why am I getting an undefined 'children' call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to attach a class to a div after one of the buttons in my navigation has been clicked.

```
$navButtons.on('click', navigationClick);

// liseten to the navigation and add a class to the link that was selected
var $navButtons = $('nav a');

var $currentListItem = $('nav li')

function navigationClick(){
  console.log("click");

  // if there is a class to remove, remove it
  // currentListItem.children('div').removeClass("nav-selected");

  var index = $navButtons.index(this);
  console.log(index);

  $currentListItem = $currentListItem[index];

  console.log($currentListItem);  = <li>
  $currentListItem.children('div').addClass("nav-selected");
}
```

When I try to execute this code I get the error:

> Cannot read property .children' of undefined.

I'm not sure why its saying `$currentListItem` is undefined as I check with a console log right above it, I get back that it is a `li` item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is due to this line:

```
$currentListItem = $currentListItem[index];
```

Here you are accessing a jQuery object by index, which returns an Element object, not a jQuery object. In turn, Elements do not have a `children()` method, hence the error you see.

To fix this, call `eq()` instead to get the element in the jQuery collection by index:

```
$navButtons.on('click', navigationClick);

var $navButtons = $('nav a');
var $currentListItem = $('nav li')

function navigationClick() {
  var index = $navButtons.index(this);
  $currentListItem = $currentListItem.eq(index); // note .eq() here
  $currentListItem.children('div').addClass("nav-selected");
}
```